# How can i write to a .txt file stored on an online server in Java?

Tags: java

Heyy. I want to use java to write specific Strings to a .txt file which I hosted on my domain on awardspace. On awardspace, I edited the permissions so reading and writing is allowed. But for now I only figured out how to read from the file, and it works. Is there a way I can write to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple method to append to a file. Just pass in the path of the file and the data to write to the file.

I normally use UTF-8 to ensure any special characters come out correctly.

```
public static void appendToFileUtf8(String file, String data) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
        OutputStreamWriter outwrite = new OutputStreamWriter(fout, "UTF-8");
        outwrite.write(data);
        outwrite.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error writing to file: "+file+" "+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: And String file is the url?

Comment: `String file` is the path. If you are already reading the file as you mention above, you should already have the path. If not, you can get the path of a file with `File.getAbsolutePath()`

Comment: the .txt file is hosted on awardspace, a free hosting service on my domain, and the java file is on my pc. I managed to read the file, and it prints me the correct content, but i cannot write to it. I tried URLConnection and all kind of writing methods, nothing works.